# How to find the congruence relation for the summation $\sum_{\substack{m<n_1<\cdots<n_r<p \\ n_i \equiv i \pmod 2}}\frac{1}{n_1\ldots n_r}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number and $j\ge 0$. By changing the variables $n_i \mapsto p-n_i$, I know that
$$\sum_{m<n_1<\cdots<n_r<p}\frac{1}{n_1\ldots n_r} \equiv (-1)^r \sum_{0<n_r< \ldots <n_1<p-m} \frac{1}{n_1\ldots n_r} \pmod p.$$

I want to know how the above congruence works when we have the summation
$$\sum_{\substack{m<n_1<\cdots<n_r<p \\ n_i \equiv i \pmod 2}}\frac{1}{n_1\ldots n_r}$$

Comment: When $i$ is even, $n_i \equiv i \bmod 2$ is conventionally set as $0$. That makes the summand undefined for $i>1$. Do you intend that when $i$ is even, we consider that $n_i \equiv 2 \bmod 2$?

Comment: @KeithBackman $n_i \equiv i \pmod 2$ means that $n_i$’s have odd, even, odd, even,...  values alternately.

Comment: @KeithBackman The inequality symbol is also undefined for residues, so the summation is evidently taken over natural numbers (which are then turned into residues for the summands of course)..